# How to copy and paste the web page into email using javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, user-interface

**I am working on some stuff where I have to need copy the web page and when I copied that page I will be able to paste that web page in email and can send as it is to someone. The below code only works with to copy the text or html tags but I need to copy whole page as it is. If there is some way let me know.**

```
<p id="p1">P1: I am paragraph 1</p>
<p id="p2">P2: I am a second paragraph</p>
<button onclick="copyToClipboard('p1')">Copy P1</button>
<button onclick="copyToClipboard('p2')">Copy P2</button>
```

```
function copyToClipboard(elementId) {

 // Create a "hidden" input
 var aux = document.createElement("input");

 // Assign it the value of the specified element
 aux.setAttribute("value", document.getElementById(elementId).innerHTML);

 // Append it to the body
 document.body.appendChild(aux);

 // Highlight its content
 aux.select();

 // Copy the highlighted text
 document.execCommand("copy");

 // Remove it from the body
 document.body.removeChild(aux);

}
```

Comment: You cannot. I mean you can but don't. You can get the entire BODY of a website, but after you paste it into an email those HTML is not valid HTML-email and will never look good across mail clients. I mean... can you explain your issue? What's your problem? What are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: what are you trying to achieve? pasting the page's text to an e-mail? pasting the structure (=html) to an e-mail? or pasting the whole thing including styles and images to an e-mail?

Comment: Yes I am trying to copy whole web page including the css and images. And currently I have used inline css for the page. Here is link of web page http://112.196.20.243:8194/wpb_appointments/raman-at-1111-am-11/

Comment: Actually I want to copy this web page http://112.196.20.243:8194/wpb_appointments/raman-at-1111-am-11/ and when I paste it into email I will show exactly same as the web page. So basically I have the issue of copy and paste the web page

Comment: Is there any event or trigger that can copy the whole web page like ctrl+a and ctrl+c?

Comment: when there are no outside ressources like images or css-files you can use  Vicky_Thinking's solution. but be aware that the E-Mail will only be readable when the recipient's client renders HTML-files. and there is no way to secure that the layout would get fuzzed up

Comment: Thanks @Woncker but I have used this  "document.documentElement.outerHTML " and it only copied the html tags but I want the web view as well. E.g when we on a web page and copy the copy with ctrl+a and then ctrl+c and when we paste the content into mail it will show as it is like the web page, that I exactly want.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the complete document html, you can use below

```
**document.documentElement.outerHTML**
```